# Provision ubuntu/xenial64 using Vagrant and Ansible

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to create an [ubuntu/xenial64](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64) vm with Vagrant and provision it using Ansible. Installed versions of tools are:

Vagrant: **2.0.0**
Ansible: **2.3.2.0**
Python: **2.7.10**
Virtualbox: **5.1.30**

These are the contents of directory in which I am running `vagrant up`:

```
├── Vagrantfile
└── playbooks
    ├── inventory
    ├── main.yml
    └── vars.yml
```

These are the contents of `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.ssh.insert_key = true

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "ubuntu"
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 2
  end

  config.vm.hostname = "ubuntu"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.7"

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbooks/main.yml"
    ansible.sudo = true
    ansible.verbose = true
    ansible.inventory_path = "playbooks/inventory"
    ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
  end

end
```

`playbooks/main.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: ubuntu
  become: yes

  vars_files:
    - vars.yml

  roles:
    - geerlingguy.docker
```

`playbooks/inventory`:

```
[ubuntu]
192.168.33.7

[ubuntu:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

playbooks/vars.yml:

```
docker_edition: 'ce'
docker_package: "docker-{{ docker_edition }}"
docker_package_state: present
```

When I run `vagrant up` the output is:

```
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 5.0.40
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/danilo/tutorials/ansible ubuntu
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...
    default: Running ansible-playbook...
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o IdentityFile=/Users/danilo/tutorials/ansible ubuntu/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' ansible-playbook --connection=ssh --timeout=30 --extra-vars=ansible_user\=\'ubuntu\' --limit="default" --inventory-file=playbooks/inventory --become -v playbooks/main.yml
No config file found; using defaults
ERROR! Specified --limit does not match any hosts
Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

However, `vagrant ssh` works as expected. Any ideas what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you use `hosts: ubuntu` then you must define named machine:

```
config.vm.define "ubuntu" do |ubuntu|
  ubuntu.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbooks/main.yml"
    ansible.sudo = true
    ansible.verbose = true
    ansible.inventory_path = "playbooks/inventory"
    ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
  end
end
```

Otherwise change to `hosts: default` in the play.

But then...

- I have no idea why you try to provision via `192.168.33.7` - it seems completely unnecessary for this use case - you can remove the `ansible.inventory_path` from `Vagrantfile`
- in the same inventory file you specify user `vagrant` which is not configured on `ubuntu/xenial64` box
- `ansible.sudo` is also not necessary in the `Vagrantfile`
- running Ansible this way on `ubuntu/xenial64` way will likely fail for the lack of Python 2

Comment: After making these changes and running again, I get "PLAY [192.168.33.7] ************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched"

Comment: Please try harder.